# flushleft in a caption compiles but has error

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, alignment, text

So there is possibly a simpler way of doing this so if I am doing it entirely wrong please do correct my method but I have...

```
\usepackage[justification=centering, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \framebox{\parbox{0.7\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Picture.jpg}}}

    \caption{\textbf{Title if you will but centred and bold}

    \begin{flushleft}
    Fairly concise but slightly longer description of the figure but all text to be aligned to the left 
    margin as per the main body of text.
    \end{flushleft}}

    \label{mylabel}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

to hopefully get something that looks a bit like [image]

My code workds well but I get two error codes:

1) Leaders not followed by proper glue.

\hfill 
l.7 ...e {James2006}. \end {flushleft}\relax }}{5}
                                                  %
You should say `\leaders '.
I found the , but there's no suitable
, so I'm ignoring these leaders.

[9

2)LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

I have many figures and after I do that for the first figure, it fails to work for the rest of them. I would be very grateful for any advice :)

Comment: Regarding: "code workds well but I get two error codes": As soon as you get an error message, don't look at the pdf but try to remove the errors first. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: Sorry! Yes I always try to remove errors from the code then and there and normally can find the answers online, maybe a better way would be to suggest that they aren't fatal errors

Comment: Do you want the frame around the image or around the caption and the descriptive text or around all three elements?

Comment: sorry I know my example has a box around the comment. I only have a box around the figure in the latex document and I think I am happy with that and not the caption

Comment: Regarding the desired alignment of the descriptive text: Should it span the whole text width of just the widt of the corrensponding image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a bunch of different options. Red lines indicate the margins.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=centering, labelfont=bf, font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{showframe} % remove in actual document
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}  % remove in actual document
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
        \begin{framed}
            \includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Picture.jpg}
            \caption{Title if you will but centred and bold}
            \label{mylabel}
            \begin{flushleft}
                Fairly concise but slightly longer description of the figure but all text to be aligned to the left 
                margin as per the main body of text.
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{framed}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Picture.jpg}
        \begin{framed}
            \caption{Title if you will but centred and bold}
            \label{mylabel2}
            \begin{flushleft}
                Fairly concise but slightly longer description of the figure but all text to be aligned to the left 
                margin as per the main body of text.
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{framed}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
        \begin{framed}
            \includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Picture.jpg}
        \end{framed}
        \caption{Title if you will but centred and bold}
        \label{mylabel3}
        \begin{flushleft}
            Fairly concise but slightly longer description of the figure but all text to be aligned to the left 
            margin as per the main body of text.
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \framebox{\parbox{0.7\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Picture.jpg}}}

    \caption{Title if you will but centred and bold}\label{mylabel4}

    \begin{flushleft}
    Fairly concise but slightly longer description of the figure but all text to be aligned to the left 
    margin as per the main body of text.
    \end{flushleft}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This should probably go in a separate question but if I would like that text to be justified instead of flushleft, is there an alternative command that could be used?

Comment: So that was just lazy of me. To answer the comment above I used..\usepackage{ragged2e} package with the command \justify{blahdeblah blah blah} to justify the longer caption. Works well. Thank you very much. Please remove if it detracts from your answer

Comment: @user209547: Which of the versions did you end up chosing?

Comment: I used the template for figure 4. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=centering, font=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \framebox{\parbox{0.7\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Picture.jpg}}}

    \parbox{0.7\linewidth}{
    \caption{Title if you will but centred and bold}

     Fairly concise but slightly longer description of the figure but all text to be aligned to the left margin as per the main body of text.
    }
    \label{mylabel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]